# Hive query getting stuck in the middle of execution

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive

Colleagues,

I'm facing with an issue while execution of bash file with sql script in hive  - it always stuck at the same place map=100%, reduce=67%

I tried to play with mappers and reducers number with different variations and other tunning characteristics:

```
SET hive.exec.parallel=true;
SET hive.default.fileformat=RCFILE;
SET hive.stats.autogather=false;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true; 
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec; 
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
SET hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat;
```

But result still the same - it continuously return 67% of reducing progress.

Hive version - 0.13.0.2.X.X.X

SQL contains table creation from several source - simple join of several tables.

Any ideas how to tune this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpfull - output info http://www.filedropper.com/response

Comment: How about some feedback on offered answer(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as found out there were several duplicated records and this was the cause why execution was stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The phases of a Reducer are:

- Shuffle
- Sort
- Reduce

Getting stuck @ 67% indicates that the Shuffle and Sort have completed but none of your partitions are able to succeed in the Reduce phase. The Reduce phase is your actual Reducer code. This indicates your code is unable to complete. You should examine your code and also look at the hive logs to see why your code is unable to be run.